# Combining window restoration with visual state preservation

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm happily upgrading a large macOS app to adopt some modern (10.9+) frameworks.

I was particularly keen to adopt the baked-in view state preservation and restoration added in 10.7 (`-encodeRestoreStateWithCoder:`, `-restoreStateWithCoder:`, `-invalidateRestorableState`, et. al.).

After updating a few window and view classes, I discovered—much to my chagrin—that this mechanism is *only* used by macOS to restore the state of windows left open when you quit the app. It does not preserve their state if the user manually closes and then reopens them, which is what I want.

Sooooooooo

I very much like the restorable state mechanism provided by Cocoa and would like to leverage it to provide my own persistent view state. I'm particularly keen on this because Cocoa already does about 80% of the work I need (saving window position, tab view selection, split view divider locations, table header order, and so on).

The documentation for `-restoreStateWithCoder:` states that "You can also use this method to reconfigure the responder to its previous appearance," from which I infer that you are free to call these encode/restore methods to preserve, and later restore, the visual state of your window as you please.

The questions now are how to reuse Cocoa's state restoration independently of, and without stepping on, the built-in window restoration mechanism. Specifically:

- I assume I'll need to manually invoke `-encodeRestoreStateWithCoder`
  of the window with my own NSCoder when closing the window and
  preserve the archived results somewhere (user defaults or the
  document itself).
- I assume I can send `-restoreStateWithCoder:` when the
  window/document is reopened, but how do I know that Cocoa isn't going
  to call it again to perform window restoration. Or maybe it doesn't
  matter (just allow the state to be restored twice)?
- At what point in the window creation is it safe to call
  `-restoreStateWithCoder:`?

Comment: After much experimentation, I concluded that Cocoa's view state preservation service can't be exploited outside of its intended purpose. As an example, if you arbitrarily invoke `-encodeRestoreStateWithCoder:` it will often crash. I ultimately ended up creating my own, fairly lightweight, state preservation and restoration service as a category of NSWindow. If someone begs, I'll clean it up and put it on GitHub.